# CMake Error: cmake don't find source directory or CMakeLists.txt (installing Ogre3D)

Tags: cmake, ogre

so I've tried to use the cmake on ogre to install it but every time I use the command in the directory build :

```
cmake ..
```

I've got this error which show up :

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/.../TPs/ogre" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

and after doing :

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/usr/share/OGRE/cmake/modules/
```

the error transformed in :

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/.../TPs/ogre" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

although it got a CMakeLists.txt.

I've got cmake 2.8.XXX version and python 2.7.XXX, I've tried to use cmake-gui but it also gave me an error about the CMakeCache ...

So do you have any advice?

**EDIT :** Ok it works, moral of the story, even if you strongly want it, don't ever put '\' in folder names !

Comment: ***it also gave me an error about the CMakeCache*** Maybe you should clean your build folder. Then try again. Perhaps your `CMakeCache.txt` has some bad cached values related to your previous failed attempts.

Comment: You are calling CMake the wrong way. First the -D arguemtns, then the path to the source directoty (.. in your case)

Comment: My build folder is always empty it doesn't even create a single file when I'm trying to do a cmake. And the order of flags in cmake is not important either way it doesn't work I still got the first error.

Comment: ***if you strongly want it, don't ever put '\' in folder names !*** '\' is the escape character in CMake.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have activated your virtual env. If you are not, then delete previus build folder.  Activate virtual env you want. Make new build folder inside opencv. Then execute cmake.